# `To analyze logical forms of following statements

Tags: logic

(a). Either John and Bill are both telling the truth, or neither of them is

Let A = John is telling truth
   ,   B= Bill is telling truth

Then i do this as follows : (A and B ) or (notA and not B)

(b).  I will have either fish or chicken, but i won't have both fish and potatoes

F = I will have fish. C = i will have Chicken. P= I will have potatoes

so , (F or C) and (notF and notP)

(c) $3$ is common divisor of $6,9$ and $15$

A = 3 is divisor of 6,

B = 3 is divisor of 9,

C = 3 is divisor of 15

so it is (A and B and C ).

(d) Alice and Bob are not both in the room

A= Alice is in the room, B= Bob is in the room

so it is, (A and (notB)) or (notA and B)

Are these correct ? Thank you

Comment: b) and d) are not correct. Just the last clause of b) is rendered wrong: "but i won't have both fish and potatoes" is "and not (F and P)". d) is simply "not (A and B)". This is true when at most one of Alice nor Bob is in the room; your rendering is true when exactly one of them is.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks. so d simply means that rom is empty, right ?

Comment: No! For various reasons, no. There might be 100 other people in the room; the sentence is indifferent. However many people are in the room — 0, 1, 2, 17, ... — both Bob and Alice are not *both* among them at the same time. Perhaps nobody is in the room; perhaps just Bob, or just Alice; perhaps Bob and Fred, or Alice and Joe; perhaps Alice, Fred and Joe; and so on. But not Bob and Alice; not Bob, Alice and Fred, etc.

Comment: @BrianO ok Thank you